# Does Adobe PDF reader have a browser-like "go back" button after clicking a hyperlink?

Tags: pdf, adobe-reader

Firstly, I know that I can use "<kbd>Alt</kbd>+Left Arrow" to go back after clicking a hyperlink. Adobe PDF refers to this functionality as "previous view".

However, what I am looking for is slightly different. What I want to do is:

1. Click on a hyperlink at point A that takes me to another point B in the same document.
2. Read from point B for a while. Perhaps I have already scrolled to another page in the document (say, I am now at point C). But during this process, I do not click another hyperlink.
3. Now, I want to go back to point A, where the hyperlink is located.

The "previous view" functionality does not allow me to do this. Specifically, if I use "Alt + Left Arrow," it takes me to the place where I performed the last "page scroll down" activity.

In contrast, if I use a web browser such as Firefox to open the PDF file, "Alt + Left Arrow" will complete the above task exactly as I expect.

My question is:

##### Is there a way to configure Adobe PDF Reader to complete the above task like a web browser?

I know that there are other PDF readers that allow me to do this. For example, the Skim reader distinguishes between "previous" and "back," where the "previous" button acts exactly like Adobe PDF Reader while the "back" button acts exactly like a web browser, as I described above.

However, these PDF readers are limited in other respects (e.g., they do not support adding bookmarks, etc.). Therefore, I am particularly interested in Adobe in this question.